# Mysql remove duplicate from a row and update the row

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table  like

```
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| col_key         |member_column                                                  | weight  |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 4:20131205:0922 | 018210020504;4.1672|018210020504;4.1672                       |  8.3344 |
| 4:20131204:0923 | 015819070006;13.8584|015819070006;13.8584                     | 27.7168 |
| 4:20131202:0922 | 018710040303;8.7864                                           |  8.7864 |
| 4:20131204:0923 | 017319010003;2.7044|017319010004;2.7044                       |  5.4088 |
| 4:20131202:0922 | 055320020104;7.3357                                           |  7.3357 |
| 4:20131217:0922 | 019120020404;7.8727|019120020404;7.8727                       | 15.7454 |
| 4:20131223:0923 | 011820010203;11.5213                                          | 11.5213 |
| 4:20131216:0925 | 018320010403;13.7416                                          | 13.7416 |
| 4:20131217:0922 | 017420020205;6.7384                                           |  6.7384 |
| 4:20131217:0922 | 019723010104;4.3660|050122010004;12.1407|050122010003;12.1407 | 28.6474 |
| 4:20131224:0926 | 022923040107;10.2461|022923040106;10.2461                     | 20.4922 |
| 4:20131216:0925 | 050122010004;12.1407|050122010003;12.1407                     | 24.2814 |
| 4:20131216:0925 | 061020030007;3.8048                                           |  3.8048 |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Here member_columns has values different member:weight which is | separated. Weight columns has total weight for the member in a particular row.

We need to remove duplicate members from the member_columns and update the weight correspondingly.
Example:

row with `col_key 4:20131205:0922` has member_column in which members are repeated .
I need this columns updated to

```
4:20131205:0922 | 018210020504;4.1672   |  4.1672
```

Similarly for the column

```
4:20131217:0922 | 019723010104;4.3660|050122010004;12.1407|050122010003;12.1407|28.6474
```

I need it to be updated as

```
4:20131217:0922 | 019723010104;4.3660|050122010004;12.1407|16.5067
```

I was looking towards cursor for the solution but learn that cursor do not update the actual data.

Please HELP .

Comment: If you need to work with separate value in your delimiter-separated-list, then storing it such way is bad idea. So first step is: normalize your data. If you need to work with separate values - the _store values in separate table_. You should not try to resolve such string operations in DBMS. If changing structure is impossible, use application then.

Comment: As a side note, when a big part of the query is string manipulation to get to the actual data to query, it's an indication that the database design is not done correctly. There is no way for the database to do this query in an efficient manner.

Comment: Why should´nt you be able to update within a cursor? Just save the ID into a variable and perform the update. On the general table design i agree with ALma Do and Joachim to separate the values into single columns.

Comment: By MySql 5.5 documentation. It says that cursors are read-only and can not be used to update.

Answer (score 0):

For this approach, you will need to take help from any server side script. So the Process to follow would be

1) select all rows having member_column as your resultset field from the table narrowing down by any condition of your choice

2) Iterate the result set

3) Explode the member_column field by "|" and form an array of strings. which would come as 
array("4:20131217:0922", "019723010104;4.3660","050122010004;12.1407","16.5067");

4) Do all your computation and remove duplicates

5) once you have a unique array, implode it back with dash "|"

6) update the row back.

Hope it helps :)